# Excel VBA: Setting a Workbook-level default save directory

Tags: excel, vba

I want my workbook to have a default save directory, e.g. "n:\mydirectory\hello", So each time I open it and try to save it, it will suggest this directory regardless of which other Workbooks I have saved in other paths recently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `Workbook_Activate` event, you can change the "current directory" with the `ChDir` statement so that whenever you are working within this file, the default save directory will be changed to what you want.

Note: this will only help for new files that have not yet been saved; existing files, even if you do a Save-As will default to their own directory.

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is specific to a single workbook (say, a template you regularly fill out and save as another filename), you could write a macro in that workbook to perform the Save As operation into the same folder (or some other static folder) using either a dialog or data from the spreadsheet to determine the new filename.

If the issue is that you just don't like saving files to "My Documents" by default, you can change Excel's default save location across the board. This setting is in the options (the exact location depends on which Excel version you're using).

Comment: The first scenario is the closest. The issue is that I work in similar sheets every day and I want to save it with a new name in the same directory daily, however I have worked with many sheets since yesterday and I want this sheet to always choose a my certain directory as default. I know that you can trigger VBA macros from a lot of events and I want my code to be in some sort of BeforeSave event.

Comment: You could use the ``ChDir`` statement to change the directory and you could do this on the ``Workbook_Activate`` event.

Comment: @RachelHettinger - thats worth an answer post rather than comment :)